# How do I plot an image from phylopic in top right corner of my ggplot graph in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to import a silhouette of a torpedo ray into a ggplot bargraph. I want one image in the top right corner of each of my 3 facet wrapped graphs. When I try to plot it I get this error `Error in img[, , 1] : incorrect number of dimensions` and I have no idea how to fix it. Here is the code I'm using to plot it...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rphylopic)
library(RCurl)
library(png)

#sample data
bargraph_dets_temp1 = data.frame(Zone = as.factor(sample(c(1,2,3,4), 22, replace = T)),
                                month = sample(month.abb, 22, replace = T),
                                year = sample(c(2016, 2017, 2018), 22, replace = T),
                                num_unique_tags = sample(c(1:9), 22, replace = T),
                                Season = sample(c("summer", "fall", "spring", "winter"), 22, replace =T))

#import phylopic
rayurl = "http://phylopic.org/assets/images/submissions/a3b3e80c-22f2-4b8f-a3ac-42fe1583e0be.thumb.png"

raylogo = readPNG(getURLContent(rayurl), native = T)


#Bargraph of ONLY the unique detections
ggplot(bargraph_dets_temp1, aes(x = Season)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Zone, 
               y = bargraph_dets_temp1$num_unique_tags), 
           position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(vars(year)) +
add_phylopic(raylogo)
```

Does anyone know how to add this silhouette into the graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `add_phylopic` is taking only `array` objects. So, you can maybe find a way to transform your `nativeraster` object into an `array`.

Alternatively, you can use `rasterGrob` function from `grid` package to transform your image into a suitable format for `ggplot` and place it using `annotation_custom`:

```r
library(grid)
raylogo = readPNG(getURLContent(rayurl), native = T)
ray2 <- rasterGrob(raylogo, interpolate=TRUE)

ggplot(bargraph_dets_temp1, aes(x = Season)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Zone, 
               y = bargraph_dets_temp1$num_unique_tags), 
           position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(vars(year)) +
  annotation_custom(ray2, xmin=3.5, xmax=4, ymin=7.5, ymax=Inf)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?